# How to create a surface or 3D Gaussian plot of such?

Tags: r, matlab, plot, graph, 3d

I want to create a surface graph or mesh of the following 2D plots of binary class data. The first graph is a simple representation of one binary class data. The second 2D graph, we see red and black circles around points. Red means source dataset and black means target dataset. How can I create surface graph of X1,X2,P(Y)? The "Z' coordinate being P(Y) of the instance. Basically, I want these points to create peaks such as in a surface graph. I tried `surf` and `mesh` but I am not doing it properly since Z must be a function of X and Y. If you have suggestions of making such graph in R or Python feel free to do so. I want the result to be similar to graph 3.

**Graph 1**

[image]

**Graph 2**

[image]

**Graph 3 Target Result**

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you tried and why it didn't fit your needs?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I told you, I used `surf` and `meshgrid` in Matlab but was not able to produce the needed resutls

Comment: I ask because `surf` and `meshgrid` are what you need to produce that plot. If you've tried those, and failed, it would be good to know how you tried to use them so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a form to do it in R but think [GNUPLOT](http://www.gnuplot.info/) makes it in a very easy way. I suppose you may arrange your data in a file *data_file.txt* containing only a matrix similar to this one:

> 0.322 0.194 0.181 0.311 0.142 0.096
>
> 0.294 0.535 0.221 0.578 0.289 0.154
>
> 0.364 0.07 0.078 0.174 0.229 0.265

The gnu code below produces and plot splines that adjust to the data and plot it in a very aestetical way:

```
reset
set terminal win

set ticslevel 0
set xlabel 'Length position'  rotate parallel offset -2,-1
set ylabel 'Width position'   rotate parallel
set zlabel 'Absorbance' rotate parallel
set pm3d
set style fill transparent solid 0.55
set palette color negative
#set view equal xy 
set xtics ("1" 0, "2" 1, "3" 2, "4" 3, "5" 4, "6" 5)
set ytics ("1" 0, "2" 1, "3" 2)

set dgrid3d 40,40 splines
splot 'data_file.txt' matrix w l lw 0.6 lc rgbcolor 'black'


set terminal pdf
set output "name_of_output_file.pdf"
replot
```

Result:
[image: Example of plot produced]

The disadvantage is that you must set the tics manually and probably restructure your data but this can be done in R to produce the file that is going to be read by GNUplot .

Comment: The data you mentioned above, are the rows x,y,z or are the columns?

Comment: Those are only the z values, the x and y must be at regular distances and must be configured in the tics